# How to define Array in XML field - Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, xml

I have try to define a array in media field name in joomla xml file.but it doesn't work. 
[image: here what I want]

```
<field name="s1img[]" label="Image 1" type="media" directory="Images" />      
<field name="imgSetting[]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting" description="" size="60"/>

<field name="s1img[]" label="Image 2" type="media" directory="Images" />
<field name="imgSetting[]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting" description="" size="60"/>

<field name="s1img[]" label="Image 3" type="media" directory="Images" />
<field name="imgSetting[]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting" description="" size="60"/>
```

When i used this code it looks like this.
[image: Only Show Last field]

How to fix this..?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is not how it works in Joomla. Your fields have to have unique names.

If you only have these 3 fields, I would suggest to name your fields s1img_1, imgSetting_1, s1img_2, ... This will make things easier to save into database as well.

If the number of fields will by dynamic, you should consider using the new [subform field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type). This allows you to build repeatable form fields.

Comment: if there any solution for this? i want to this images path in one array. i'm using it now these all values in one array..

Comment: Why one array? You can't save arrays directly into database either. 
But you could override your models save and load functions to save and load all 3 values into/from one database field.